# Memory Allocation of Python Sub-Processes Within Pyspark Driver

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When creating new Python processes within PySpark driver (e.g. with JobLib or other multi-processing library), do those processes share the Spark driver memory, or are they allocated memory outside of that PySpark driver JVM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python driver memory is not accounted in `spark.driver.memory` (sames as `spark.executor.memory` in case of workers). `spark.*.memory` settings are used only for on-heap Java memory allocation.

All other forms of memory allocation (off-heap, native memory like in case of Python and such) are covered by `spark.driver.memoryOverhead` and equivalent settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you point me to a good source of detailed information about this topic?

I'm still not sure I completely follow what you're saying. 

Example:
- PySpark job running in cluster mode with the driver on a node with 8 GB of RAM
- spark.driver.memory=7G, spark.driver.memoryOverhead=1G
If I create a pandas dataframe in my python script larger than 1GB in size, will that kill the driver container?